# with postgres, how to do an upsert of rows based on a timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have the following used in a transaction

```
INSERT INTO {schemaName}.{tableName}
(id, ticker, interval, ts_start, ts_end, price_top, ts_top, continuity_top, price_bottom, ts_bottom, continuity_bottom)
VALUES (@id, @ticker, @interval, @ts_start, @ts_end, @price_top, @ts_top, @continuity_top, @price_bottom, @ts_bottom, @continuity_bottom)
ON CONFLICT (ticker, interval, ts_start)
DO UPDATE SET
    ts_end = @ts_end,
    price_top = @price_top, ts_top = @ts_top, continuity_top = @continuity_top,
    price_bottom = @price_bottom, ts_bottom = @ts_bottom, continuity_bottom = @continuity_bottom
```

*ts_end* is of type TIMESTAMP and can be null.

What I would like to do is to upsert rows ONLY if the row to be inserted has a newer *ts_end* column.

The rules being:

- row doesn't exist, insert it.
- row exists AND the row to be inserted's *ts_end* is newer than the one in the table, insert it.
- skip otherwise.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a single statement. You have to query the existing row first, then insert your new row or not, depending on the outcome of the query.

I don't know if that is a problem for you, but with the method described above it can happen that a concurrent transaction commits a row with a higher timestamp *after* you inserted your row. If you want to avoid that, you need to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

The UPSERT you display would require a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(ticker, interval, ts_start)` - in which case you couldn't insert a conflicting row to begin with.

You can achieve your objective in a single query:

```
WITH input(ticker, interval, ts_start, ts_end)  AS (
   VALUES (1, 1, timestamp '2023-10-15 10:00', timestamp '2023-10-15 11:00')  -- your (typed!) input here
   -- more column values ...
   )
INSERT INTO tbl (ticker, interval, ts_start, ts_end)
SELECT * FROM input i
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t
   WHERE (i.ticker, i.interval, i.ts_start)  
      =  (t.ticker, t.interval, t.ts_start) 
   AND  t.ts_end >= i.ts_end
   );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mpexeghx)

However, this is vulnerable to concurrent write load. If concurrent transactions can commit conflicting rows in the tiny time slot between `SELECT` & `INSERT`, your requirement can be violated. The (more expensive!) [`SERIALIZABLE` isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) can protect against it (using the same query), but you must prepare to repeat the query in case of a serialization failure.

You need index support to make this fast. A PK on `(ticker, interval, ts_start, ts_end)` would do.

You may have to cast input values in a separate `VALUES` expression. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427434/939860)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)